# How am I being able to access function stack memory after returning?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

This is my code:

using namespace std;

// if memory is alloted statically then you can't access memory address after the function has returned and its stack is gone.

```
int* function(int x)
 {
  int *x_ptr = &x;
  return x_ptr;
 }

int main()
{
 int x=10;
 int *x_ptr = function(x);
 cout<<*x_ptr<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can't access memory address after the function has returned

Correct.

The behaviour of the program is undefined.